# библиотека js-cookie

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста , есть библиотека faker.js для генерации имени ,  как сделать так чтоб при первом заходе на сайт одно имя записалось в куку и даже если браузер обновлялся имя не менялось, проблема в том что при обновлении всегда новое имя ?

пример работы библиотеки js-cookie:
Cookies.set('name', 'value')
Cookies.get('name') // => 'value'

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так, например:

```
let name = Cookies.get('name');
if (!name) {
    name = generatedNewName();
    Cookies.set('name', name);
}
```

Проверяете куку. Если существует - используете ее значение, а иначе - генерируете новое значение и записываете его в куку.

Comment: А если зайти с другого браузера , кука под именем name там будет существовать или создаться новая?

Comment: В другом броузере, а режиме инкогнито или после удаления кукисов в настройках броузера - во всех этих случаях, конечно же, будет создаваться новая.